# Why is git bash behaving weird on PyCharm?

Tags: windows, pycharm, git-bash

I am using **PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)** on **Windows 8**.  I wanted to integrate Git bash in the PyCharm terminal.  I have set the shell path in the terminal application settings of PyCharm as 
    C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
The problem occurs when I activate a venv virtual ennvironment, set up using

```
python -m venv env
```

by running

```
source env/Scripts/activate
```

I think env is active as I see two parenthesis, **()** and typing *pip freeze* displays all installed packages in env. But this is accompanied with an error message that displays in the terminal

> bash: basename: command not found

This same message is logged after typing commands like *ls*, *clear* which doesn't work but *pip freeze* and *pip --version* work. And when I deactivate env, *ls*, *clear* and *pip* stopped working displaying the mentioned error message.
All this problems do not occur in the  Git bash application for Windows irrespective of whether I am in env or global environment and all commands work properly. I know I can just use Git bash instead of the integrated terminal of PyCharm but just wanted an answer to this problem.

What seems to be the problem here? Am I setting up my shell path wrongly or is this problem specific to PyCharm?

Comment: if you can check, what echo $PATH is set to now.  i wonder if a little install-elf didn't `PATH=<whatever python needs and nothing else>`.  try also a bash builtin, neither `ls` nor `clear` are, but `help`, `cd`, `pwd` are supposed to be (they have `/usr/bin` on macos and who knows what bash.exe does).  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/index.htm

Comment: I think it has got to be specific to PyCharm as every problem I have mentioned is non existent in bash of VS Code integrated using  the same shell path. I can't say the same about PyCharm professional edition though.

Comment: point is... when you know what $PATH actually is, you can see things like who might have messed it up.  if it's just Python type stuff, then yeah, pycharm.  there's also git involved.  and you. if you open another terminal - without running any pycharm, no pbm, correct?

Comment: separate from the above.  `~/.profile` and all those guys.  including any config files anywhere **once they're secret-less**  -- they're candidates for being gitted.  not github.com, just `git init`.  strip out the passwords though i think there are even packages to do that.

Comment: The problem only arises in **bash** of PyCharm. Everything works fine in bash of VS Code, Git bash for Windows, even when running the virtual environment. I think it has got to do with running the virtual environment in PyCharm. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by disabling "Activate Virtualenv" checkbox in File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal

Since, pycharm documents does not show any support for 'Git Bash', that is probably the reason for this weird behaviour.

[Terminal Options in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tc74.png)

Comment: This worked for me too, fwiw. I had the same exact problem